# Application Guava lib version conflicting with Quarkus version

Tags: quarkus

When including a not-so-recent version of Guava (20.0) in my Quarkus (0.19.1) application via a third-party lib, at runtime (mvn compile quarkus:dev), I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.net.HostAndPort.getHostText()Ljava/lang/String;
```

Upgrading to the latest snapshot of the lib solves the problem because the version of Guava has been upgraded as well. But this is not an ideal solution as the lib has not yet released in this version. Furthermore, there are libraries out there relying on Guava (on another lib used by Quarkus internals) that might never get updated.

Is there a way to isolate the Guava lib (or any other lib) used by Quarkus from the one used by applications?

**Edit**
Some more details. The issue occurs with the org.littleshoot:littleproxy 1.1.2 (https://github.com/adamfisk/LittleProxy/blob/littleproxy-1.1.2/pom.xml) which has a dependency to com.google.guava:guava 20.0

A dependency tree check shows that com.google.guava:guava *27.0.1-jre* is used instead of the 20.0 version.

```
[INFO] +- io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy:jar:0.19.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.quarkus:quarkus-undertow:jar:0.19.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.quarkus:quarkus-arc:jar:0.19.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.quarkus.arc:arc:jar:0.19.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.undertow:undertow-servlet:jar:2.0.21.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.undertow:undertow-core:jar:2.0.21.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet:jboss-servlet-api_4.0_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.xnio:xnio-nio:jar:3.7.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.xnio:xnio-api:jar:3.7.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.microprofile.context-propagation:microprofile-context-propagation-api:jar:1.0-RC1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- javax.enterprise:cdi-api:jar:2.0.SP1:compile
[INFO] |  |        +- javax.el:javax.el-api:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- javax.interceptor:javax.interceptor-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-server-common:jar:0.19.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-common:jar:0.19.1:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-core:jar:4.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs:jboss-jaxrs-api_2.1_spec:jar:1.0.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.bind:jboss-jaxb-api_2.3_spec:jar:1.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-core-spi:jar:4.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  \- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-context-propagation:jar:4.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  \- io.smallrye:smallrye-context-propagation:jar:1.0.7:compile
[INFO] |     |  |     \- io.smallrye:smallrye-context-propagation-api:jar:1.0.7:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |     \- io.quarkus:quarkus-jaxb:jar:0.19.1:compile
[INFO] +- io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-jsonb:jar:0.19.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.quarkus:quarkus-jsonb:jar:0.19.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse:yasson:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.json.bind:javax.json.bind-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.quarkus:quarkus-jsonp:jar:0.19.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-json-binding-provider:jar:4.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish:javax.json:jar:1.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-json-p-provider:jar:4.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.littleshoot:littleproxy:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:27.0.1-jre:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.guava:failureaccess:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.guava:listenablefuture:jar:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.checkerframework:checker-qual:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:jar:1.17:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-all:jar:4.1.34.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.barchart.udt:barchart-udt-bundle:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] +- io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5:jar:0.19.1:test
[INFO] |  +- io.quarkus:quarkus-bootstrap-core:jar:0.19.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-embedder:jar:3.5.4:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:3.5.4:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:3.5.4:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:3.5.4:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:3.5.4:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:3.5.4:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-model-builder:jar:3.5.4:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-builder-support:jar:3.5.4:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.maven.resolver:maven-resolver-api:jar:1.1.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.maven.resolver:maven-resolver-util:jar:1.1.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.maven.shared:maven-shared-utils:jar:3.2.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.inject:guice:jar:no_aop:4.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- javax.annotation:jsr250-api:jar:1.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.24:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds:jar:2.5.2:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.eclipse.sisu:org.eclipse.sisu.plexus:jar:0.3.3:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:jar:1.7.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.4:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-settings-builder:jar:3.5.4:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.24:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:jar:1.4:test
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher:jar:1.4:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-resolver-provider:jar:3.5.4:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:3.5.4:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.maven.resolver:maven-resolver-spi:jar:1.1.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.maven.resolver:maven-resolver-impl:jar:1.1.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven.resolver:maven-resolver-connector-basic:jar:1.1.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven.resolver:maven-resolver-transport-file:jar:1.1.1:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.maven.resolver:maven-resolver-transport-http:jar:1.1.1:test
[INFO] |  |     \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:test
[INFO] |  +- io.quarkus:quarkus-test-common:jar:0.19.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- io.quarkus:quarkus-core-deployment:jar:0.19.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.3:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.jboss.invocation:jboss-invocation:jar:1.5.2.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.jboss.classfilewriter:jboss-classfilewriter:jar:1.2.4.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.quarkus.gizmo:gizmo:jar:1.0.0.Alpha5:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.ow2.asm:asm-util:jar:7.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |     +- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:jar:7.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:jar:7.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:7.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.quarkus:quarkus-builder:jar:0.19.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- io.quarkus:quarkus-jsonp-deployment:jar:0.19.1:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.1.1.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.5.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.5.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.5.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] |  \- io.quarkus:quarkus-core:jar:0.19.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] |     +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.smallrye:smallrye-config:jar:1.3.5:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.eclipse.microprofile.config:microprofile-config-api:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |     |     \- org.osgi:org.osgi.annotation.versioning:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.jboss.logmanager:jboss-logmanager-embedded:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:jar:2.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.jboss.threads:jboss-threads:jar:3.0.0.Beta4:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.jboss.slf4j:slf4j-jboss-logging:jar:1.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.graalvm.sdk:graal-sdk:jar:19.0.2:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.wildfly.common:wildfly-common:jar:1.5.0.Final-format-001:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.wildfly.security:wildfly-elytron-ssl:jar:2.0.0.Alpha4:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.wildfly.security:wildfly-elytron-auth-server:jar:2.0.0.Alpha4:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  \- org.wildfly.security:wildfly-elytron-permission:jar:2.0.0.Alpha4:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.wildfly.security:wildfly-elytron-base:jar:2.0.0.Alpha4:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.wildfly.security:wildfly-elytron-credential:jar:2.0.0.Alpha4:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  +- org.wildfly.security:wildfly-elytron-keystore:jar:2.0.0.Alpha4:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  \- org.wildfly.security:wildfly-elytron-provider-util:jar:2.0.0.Alpha4:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.wildfly.security:wildfly-elytron-auth:jar:2.0.0.Alpha4:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.wildfly.security:wildfly-elytron-util:jar:2.0.0.Alpha4:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.wildfly.security:wildfly-elytron-x500:jar:2.0.0.Alpha4:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.wildfly.security:wildfly-elytron-x500-cert:jar:2.0.0.Alpha4:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.wildfly.security:wildfly-elytron-asn1:jar:2.0.0.Alpha4:compile
[INFO] |        \- org.wildfly.security:wildfly-elytron-x500-cert-util:jar:2.0.0.Alpha4:compile
[INFO] \- io.rest-assured:rest-assured:jar:3.3.0:test
[INFO]    +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:jar:2.4.15:test
[INFO]    +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-xml:jar:2.4.15:test
[INFO]    +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.9:test
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.11:test
[INFO]    |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:test
[INFO]    |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.11:test
[INFO]    +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.5.3:test
[INFO]    +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO]    +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO]    +- org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup:tagsoup:jar:1.2.1:test
[INFO]    +- io.rest-assured:json-path:jar:3.3.0:test
[INFO]    |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-json:jar:2.4.15:test
[INFO]    |  \- io.rest-assured:rest-assured-common:jar:3.3.0:test
[INFO]    \- io.rest-assured:xml-path:jar:3.3.0:test
[INFO]       +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO]       \- org.apache.sling:org.apache.sling.javax.activation:jar:0.1.0:test
```

**Edit 2**: adding the full stacktrance

```
2019-08-06 14:44:07,908 INFO  [io.qua.dep.QuarkusAugmentor] (main) Beginning quarkus augmentation
2019-08-06 14:44:09,055 INFO  [io.qua.dep.QuarkusAugmentor] (main) Quarkus augmentation completed in 1147ms
2019-08-06 14:44:10,208 INFO  [com.agf.orb.orm.LifecycleManager] (main) Bootstrap proxy on /127.0.0.1:8888
2019-08-06 14:44:10,346 INFO  [com.agf.orb.orm.LifecycleManager] (main) Loaded config file from D:/dev/tmp/chaos.conf
2019-08-06 14:44:10,346 INFO  [com.agf.orb.orm.LifecycleManager] (main) Chaos Proxy started. Read/Write/Delete configuration via GET|PUT|DELETE /resources/chaos/conf.
2019-08-06 14:44:10,348 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Quarkus 0.19.1 started in 2.657s. Listening on: http://[::]:18080
2019-08-06 14:44:10,349 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Installed features: [cdi, resteasy, resteasy-jsonb]
2019-08-06 14:44:18,744 ERROR [org.lit.pro.imp.ClientToProxyConnection] (LittleProxy-0-ClientToProxyWorker-0) (AWAITING_INITIAL) [id: 0x95348e38, L:/127.0.0.1:8888 - R:/127.0.0.1:63611]: Caught an exception on ClientToProxyConnection: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.net.HostAndPort.getHostText()Ljava/lang/String;
        at org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.ProxyToServerConnection.addressFor(ProxyToServerConnection.java:961)
        at org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.ProxyToServerConnection.setupConnectionParameters(ProxyToServerConnection.java:832)
        at org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.ProxyToServerConnection.<init>(ProxyToServerConnection.java:199)
        at org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.ProxyToServerConnection.create(ProxyToServerConnection.java:173)
        at org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.ClientToProxyConnection.doReadHTTPInitial(ClientToProxyConnection.java:300)
        at org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.ClientToProxyConnection.readHTTPInitial(ClientToProxyConnection.java:206)
        at org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.ClientToProxyConnection.readHTTPInitial(ClientToProxyConnection.java:80)
        at org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.ProxyConnection.readHTTP(ProxyConnection.java:135)
        at org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.ProxyConnection.read(ProxyConnection.java:120)
        at org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.ProxyConnection.channelRead0(ProxyConnection.java:587)
        at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:337)
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:337)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:86)
        at org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.ProxyConnection$RequestReadMonitor.channelRead(ProxyConnection.java:715)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:337)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:323)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:297)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:337)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:86)
        at org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.ProxyConnection$BytesReadMonitor.channelRead(ProxyConnection.java:692)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:337)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1408)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:930)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:677)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:612)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:529)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:491)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:905)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Do you have an example application we could see? Or the output of `mvn dependency:tree` maybe?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The application is not publicly accessible but I added details in the post.

Comment: Could you please also provide a larger stacktrace so we can potentially figure out where the problem is occuring?

Comment: Just added the stacktrace. Thanks again for investigating this.

Comment: Thanks! Can you perhaps just add the appropriate Java version in `dependencyManagement` section and see if that fixes the problem?

Comment: Do you mean setting the dependency to littleproxy in the dependencyManagement? Tried this but same issue. I pushed the project to ease investigations: https://github.com/zapho/chaos-proxy/tree/master/quarkus

Comment: I'll check it out

Comment: I just used your repo and both `0.19.1` and `0.20.0` versions of Quarkus worked. Is there anything else I need to do to reproduce the problem?

Comment: The issue occurs at runtime. So, to reproduce it you need 1/ to start it 'mvn clean compile quarkus:dev' and 2/ send a request via the proxy, e.g. 'http --proxy=http:http://localhost:8888 google.com' (using Httpie here but any http client will do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get past the problem you describe by adding:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>20.0</version>
  </dependency>
```

in Maven's `dependencyManagement` section (after `littleproxy`).

Note that this will likely change in the future since guava is a transient dependency of `maven-embedder`, but the codebase of that dependency has since been [updated](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-6475) to remove guava so Quarkus needs to pick up the new version

Comment: Thanks, this works indeed. But what are the consequences of downgrading the version of Guava at runtime? Quarkus seems to need 27.0.1-jre for its runtime. AFAIK, Quarkus is not using any kind of module system or classpath isolation, so using any library with a different version than Quarkus is expecting is rather risky I would say. What's your take on this?

Comment: I would need to look into it more to tell you the truth. I would personally like it if Guava were not a dependency at all. I'll post back when I have more information

Comment: Great. Thanks for all the work. I will dig into Quarkus internals as well to try to sort this out.

Comment: I remember that it's only used for bootstrap, but I haven't dug into why. Might be worth a question on the Quarkus Zulip chat since I won't be back for a few more days

Comment: A relevant zulip discussion is here: https://quarkusio.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/187030-users/topic/Guava.20dependency.20conflict